# Aplicacion de laravel, no funciona font-awesome en el servidor de produccion (ubunu server 20)

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, ubuntu-server

llevo unos dias buscando porque no me salen los iconos de **font-awesome free** en mi servidor.
Instale el package en local, lo probe, todo ok y lo subi, una vez probado en el server me salen los cuadraditos en vez de los iconos indicando que no se cargaron.

Busque for github por si hubiera algun gist con posibles soluciones. Encontre uno que decia que mirara en la pestaña del explorador de **inspeccionar** la parte de **networks** para ver si se estaban cargando bien los iconos. Ahi encontre, efectivamente como indicaba el **gist** , que habia un problema con la carga de estos recursos, os voy a poner a continucacion lo que me indica la **pestaña network** con respecto a la carga de **font awesome**:

[image: Problema font awesome]

Asi que no se que motivo pueder, en el server hice `npm install` y `npm run dev`.

En mi fichero `app.scss` tengo los siguientes imports relacionados con `font-awesome`:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Antes tenia solo:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

Pero como veia que no iba encontre que podia ser porque habia que importar mas cosas, pero nada.
Repito, en mi local funciona todo ok, es en el **server donde no funciona**.

Aqui dejo la ruta con la que intenta cargar  en el sevidor las cosas de `font-awesome`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si no te cargan los íconos, probablemente el error es que no esté cargando tu archivo generado por laravel mix correctamente, asegúrate de tener bien referenciado el archivo en la vista principal donde quieres visualizar los íconos:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

También depende mucho de si el sitio lo montaste en un dominio o subdominio.